# Need a book for learning step by step MVC shopping cart development using Servlet/jsp|JSTL|EL etc

Tags: java, jsp, model-view-controller, servlets, shopping-cart

I have seen many book in PHP with or without framework for learning step by step project development like my most favorite book :

http://www.packtpub.com/zend-framework-18-web-application-development/book 
Which guides intermediate programmer. this book shows each and every step for developing shopping cart including:
1. MVC implementations using Zend framework
2. ACL implementations
3. Modular development - separating admin and front-end 
4. Testing using PHPUnit
5. Optimization like caching , SQL caching and optimizing in the last chapters

So we do not have any book or sample project from where I can see how can I develop aprofessional MVC shopping cart using Servlets/ jsp/ JSTL /EL? because I am good with this and right now I do not want to go for any large framework, I want start with these basic technologies, any one please help!!!!

Comment: There are good resources of these in [StackOverflow Servlets wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info), specially the links in its FAQ. Personally, I mostly enjoyed the 2nd and 5th links there.

Comment: If you really have the experience you claim, then follow the requirements of this application but using JSP/Servlets/EL + JSTL by yourself...

Comment: I am preparing a complete project with the example and soon I will also upload it to github, it is my request to please so not close question.

Comment: Good to know you work on this project and it will be available for community in github. Still, this is not proper for StackOverflow. You can post your github link elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here is a couple of books:

- [Murach's Java Servlets and JSP, 2nd
  Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1890774448) - a popular Servlets/JSP book with lots of examples and best practice descriptions. In the end it has a show-case: *Music store* e-commerce web site. Source code for the book's applications (including *musicStore* web app) can be [downloaded for free](http://www.murach.com/books/jsp2/download.htm).
  **NOTE**: This is a Servlets/JSP/JSTL/EL book. Probably the closest to what you want, if I get you right.
- [Beginning Java EE 6 with GlassFish 3 (Expert's Voice in Java
  Technology)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/143022889X) - very serious Java EE 6 book (goes beyond just Servlet/JSP). On the author's site there is a download link to the source code for the Java EE 6 web application [*Pet
  Store*](http://antoniogoncalves.org/2012/06/25/yet-another-petstore/)
  (analogous to the legendary Sun Microsystem's *Java Pet Store* reference application,
  developed by the Sun's [Java BluePrints](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_BluePrints) Program team to showcase usage of previous Java EE versions).

---

Also check out the following **free resources**:

- [The NetBeans E-commerce Tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/intro.html) - this is a multi-part tutorial, you learn how to create a simple yet effective e-commerce application that demonstrates various important
  features of Java web and EE development (goes beyond just Servlet/JSP). The completed project is also [available for download](http://netbeans.org/projects/samples/downloads/download/Samples%252FJavaEE%252Fecommerce%252FAffableBean_complete.zip) (the link is taken from the *Chapter 13. Conclusion*).
- [Official Java EE
  documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkgjw.html)
  also has several case studies (including e-commerce application *Duke’s Bookstore*) to illustrate different Java EE concepts (also goes beyond just Servlet/JSP).

Again, just some of the examples.
Hope this helps.

Comment: This is really very helped me a lot. thanks for this detail information, with all these different information I can conclude my answer. again thanks for your answer

Comment: The NetBeans E-commerce Tutorial is superb, perfect tutorial, super like :)